# Arduino Bootstrap not working - MKR WiFi 1010

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, arduino

I'm trying out the AP mode of the device, where it can serve as its own server. Most of the tutorials have been loading the html from the SD card. I can do the same, but the bootstrap of the website is not working. It just loads the basic version of the website. How can I fix this?

#### APMode.ino

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#define WEBHTM "SERVER/index.htm"
 
///////please enter your sensitive data in the Secret tab/arduino_secrets.h
char ssid[] = "MKRTEST";        // your network SSID (name)
char pass[] = "PASS";    // your network password (use for WPA, or use as key for WEP)
int keyIndex = 0;                // your network key Index number (needed only for WEP)

int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
WiFiServer server(80);

File webFile;

void setup() 
{

    //Initialize serial and wait for port to open:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while (!Serial);

    Serial.println("Access Point Web Server");


    // check for the WiFi module:
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
    }

    if(!SD.begin(4))
    {
        Serial.println("SD card not found!");
        while(1);
    }

    if (!SD.exists(WEBHTM))
    {
        Serial.println("missing index.htm!");
        while(1);
    }
    // if (!SD.exists(RESHTM))
    // {
    //     Serial.println("missing xres.htm!");
    //     while(1);
    // }


    String fv = WiFi.firmwareVersion();
    if (fv < WIFI_FIRMWARE_LATEST_VERSION) {
    Serial.println("Please upgrade the firmware");
    }

    // by default the local IP address of will be 192.168.4.1
    // you can override it with the following:
    // WiFi.config(IPAddress(10, 0, 0, 1));

    // print the network name (SSID);
    Serial.print("Creating access point named: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);

    // Create open network. Change this line if you want to create an WEP network:
    status = WiFi.beginAP(ssid);
    if (status != WL_AP_LISTENING) {
    Serial.println("Creating access point failed");
    // don't continue
    while (true);
    }

    // wait 10 seconds for connection:
    delay(10000);

    // start the web server on port 80
    server.begin();

    // you're connected now, so print out the status
    printWiFiStatus();
}


void loop() {
  // compare the previous status to the current status
  if (status != WiFi.status()) {
    // it has changed update the variable
    status = WiFi.status();

    if (status == WL_AP_CONNECTED) {
      // a device has connected to the AP
      Serial.println("Device connected to AP");
    } else {
      // a device has disconnected from the AP, and we are back in listening mode
      Serial.println("Device disconnected from AP");
    }
  }
  
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // if you get a client,
    Serial.println("new client");           // print a message out the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    while (client.connected()) {            // loop while the client's connected
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character

          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();
            webFile = SD.open(WEBHTM);
            if (webFile)
            {
              while (webFile.available())
              {
                client.write(webFile.read());
              }
              webFile.close();
            }

            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line:
            client.println();
            // break out of the while loop:
            break;
          }
          else {      // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine:
            currentLine = "";
          }
        }
        else if (c != '\r') {    // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
        if (currentLine.endsWith("POST /enterCredentials")) {
        //   digitalWrite(led, HIGH);               // GET /H turns the LED on
        }
      }
    }
    // close the connection:
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("client disconnected");
  }
}

void printWiFiStatus() {
  // print the SSID of the network you're attached to:
  Serial.print("SSID: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.SSID());

  // print your WiFi shield's IP address:
  IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(ip);

  // print where to go in a browser:
  Serial.print("To see this page in action, open a browser to http://");
  Serial.println(ip);

}
```

#### index.htm

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>LPS Server</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0">
  <h1>Low Power Sensor (LPS) Server</h1>
</div>

<div class="container" style="margin-top:30px" id="WifiDetails">
  <h3>Please enter needed Credentials</h3>
  <form action="/enterCredentials.htm" method="post"><label for="SSID">SSID:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="SSID"><label for="PASS">PASS:</label><input type="password" class="form-control" name="PASS"><label for="BROKER">Broker/Host:</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="BROKER"><label for="DEVID">Device ID:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DEVID"><input type="hidden" name="eof" value="#EOF"><br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Submit">SUBMIT</button></form>  
</div>

<div class="jumbotron text-center" style="margin-bottom:0"><p>All Rights Reserved 2020</p></div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean in "F12"?

Answer (score 1):

I use bootstrap the following way.
Download the version you need 3 or 4,
Copy the minimized versions to a dir on the sd (css and js), depending on your styling you might also need fonts like glyicons or some other icon set.

css goes into the header

```
 <!-- request default CSS from the Arduino / ESP8266 / ESP32 web server -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" charset="utf-8"> 
<!-- used with bootstrap 4 or bootstrap native -->
```

....

bootstrap js and other js end of body.

```
 <!-- request js from the Arduino / ESP8266 / ESP32 web server standard libs are in lib own in js -->

  <script src="lib/bootstrap4.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
...
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

works like a charm with webserver and async webserver as well.
 
A pro tip: To get rid of jquery I use bootstrap native and pure js